# How to Obfuscate Unrealscript code (compiled into .u files), so that Decompilers like UTPT and WOTgreal aren't able to decompile/crash?

Tags: c++, obfuscation, decompiling, decompiler, unrealscript

I'm trying to find a way to make Decompilers (like UTPT, WOTgreal) essentially fail.

The files are .uc, written in Unrealscript, compiled into a .u file

Successful Example for UTPT:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX1fD.png

I've tried simply naming the .uc files with 64 characters, which made the decompilers unable to decompile, but I ran into some other problem because of it, so I can not use that.

Comment: Mission impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a way to do this with with a `ucc` commandlet called `Editor.StripSourceCommandlet` (https://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy:Commandlet).

Comment: Sadly this only gets rid of the source code and does not obstruct decompilation at all.